# Cross compiling Apache Axis 2 C for ARM (Symbian/Meego)

Tags: compilation, arm, meego, axis2c

I have used Apache Axis 2 C to generate C++ (or is it C? - the docs do not distinguish betweeen the original Apache Axis and the newer Axis2 too well).

I intend to use these generated XML bindings in my Meego and Symbian application, the issue with this of course is that libraries that the generated files need (like axiom, libxml etc.) are are x86. I need ARM libraries. The solution to this is to cross compile Apache Axis 2 to ARM and then link to them in my application.

From the looks of it Apache Axis appears to have used Autotools, so my question is

1. Can I import Apache Axis 2 into say eclipse (or any other IDE) and just point it to the arm g++/gcc compiler and just click compile?

I'm looking for the simplest solution that will give me the .so files for Symbian/Meego.

The source code is here:

https://github.com/apache/axis2-c

And it also appears to have Visual Studio 2008 .proj files....

Any help is most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cross compile in Scratchbox, I haven't used Meego though (only Maemo).
Have a look at http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/guide/html/Developer_Library_Alternative_development_environments_Platform_SDK_user_guide.html
in Scratchbox itself it should work just like on a desktop linux

Comment: Would it work for symbian as well? Scratchbox seems like a lot of effort?

Comment: I've never used Symbian and since it uses it's own kernel and userland I doubt it will work straight away, but the principle is the same

Comment: Eclipse can work with autoconf - would it not be easier to just import it in eclipse? The biggest issue with this is would the arm g++/gcc compiler have the same parameters as the normal x86 one? Or import each module into Qt Creator?